# How to update single object property using JSONata transform operator

Tags: transform, jsonata

I'm trying to update a single property within an object using the JSONata [transform](https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform) operator. I don't want to lose any other properties from the initial object.

My input object:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "_id": "097369183479824602",
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "sku": "0230115",
    "quantity": 8
  },
  "quantityRemaining": 6
}
```

My JSONata expression:

```json
$ ~> | item | { "quantity" : quantityRemaining } |
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "_id": "097369183479824602",
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "sku": "0230115",
    "quantity": 6
  },
  "quantityRemaining": 6
}
```

But the actual object is:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "_id": "097369183479824602",
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "sku": "0230115",
    "quantity": 8
  },
  "quantityRemaining": 6
}
```

I'm not sure why the value of `item.quantity` is not being overwritten by `quantityRemaining`.
Any help is appreciated!

Interestingly, if I simply the expression to the following:

```json
$ ~> | item | { "quantity" : 3 } |
```

the output is expected:

```json
{
  "item": {
    "_id": "097369183479824602",
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "sku": "0230115",
    "quantity": 3
  },
  "quantityRemaining": 6
}
```

I'm doing all of this in the https://try.jsonata.org/ playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression - where you try and set the `quantity` - the context is set to the value of `item`. `input.item.quantityRemaining` evaluates to `undefined` and so JSONata seems to discard the value from the expression and use the one from the input.

You could use the `$$` variable, which reference the root of the input JSON, to break out of the current context.

https://docs.jsonata.org/programming#built-in-variables

```
$ ~> | item | { "quantity" : $$.quantityRemaining } |
```

You can see this working in this [JSONata playground](https://stedi.link/dA9tGap).

Note that I'm not super familiar with JSONata, and so there might be a better way to achieve what you're after.